# Idiomatic way to set simd lanes to 0 based on mask?

Tags: rust, simd

New to using rust’s `std::simd` library, and I’ve found myself encountering this scenario:

I have a mask8x8 and a u8x8, and I want to set each lane in the u8x8 to 0 if the corresponding mask is false; essentially I want to multiply them, assuming masks are the same layout as simd.

I can’t find a better way than using `mask.select(foo, u8x8::splat(0))`, though, which seems inefficient/ hard to read. Surely there’s a better way to do this?

Comment: Oh yeah I’m using std::simd/portable_simd with the type alias u8x8 for Simd<u8, 8>. Fair point about the experimental api; I assumed it was a finalized api with the natural pitfalls of rust nightly

Comment: You can follow its maturity in this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86656. Note the many unchecked boxes on things like *"What are the ideal semantics for Masks?"*.

Comment: *"seems inefficient"* - It gets optimized away by the compiler, so don't worry about performance.

Comment: The splat is irrelevant, but apparently `mask.select` manipulates the mask in a silly way: shift the mask left by 7, AND by 128, compare to zero to check if it's negative. The AND is redundant since negativity only depends on the sign, and there are nicer ways to transform 0/1 in each lane (already a poor choice to begin with) into 0/-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is not enough stability in `std::simd` to argue about best practices, especially regarding the fact that at the time of writing, you can see that in the official [feature roadmap](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86656) that the point *"What are the ideal semantics for Masks?"* does not have a checkmark yet. So you can expect this API to improve before being stabilized.

That said, thanks to Rust's trait system, you can always extend the feature set yourself, like this:

```rust
use std::simd;

trait SimdExt<T, const N: usize>
where
    T: simd::SimdElement + Default,
    simd::LaneCount<N>: simd::SupportedLaneCount,
{
    fn filter(self, mask: simd::Mask<T::Mask, N>) -> Self;
}

impl<T, const N: usize> SimdExt<T, N> for simd::Simd<T, N>
where
    T: simd::SimdElement + Default,
    simd::LaneCount<N>: simd::SupportedLaneCount,
{
    fn filter(self, mask: simd::Mask<T::Mask, N>) -> Self {
        mask.select(self, simd::Simd::<T, N>::splat(Default::default()))
    }
}
```

Then, you should be able to write:

```rust
use std::simd::{mask8x8, u8x8, ToBitMask};

fn main() {
    let data = u8x8::from_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
    let mask = mask8x8::from_bitmask(0b01010110);

    let filtered_data = data.filter(mask);

    println!("{:?}", filtered_data);
}
```

```
[0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0]
```

Proof that this is equivalent to your code: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/354e5srh8